# Superimposing a logistic line of fit

Tags: r, curve-fitting, logistic-regression

How can you superimpose a logistic curve on a plot.

```
Temp<-c(27.2,28.3,29.9) 
Temp 
male<-c(0,8,8) 
male 
female<-c(10,4,2)
female
table=read.table("E:\\Book1.txt",header=T)
attach(table) 
table 
Y=cbind(male,female) 
Y 
mylogit <- glm(Y ~ Temp, family = "binomial",table)
summary(mylogit)
```

I need to superimpose a logistic curve for both males and females

```
curve(predict(mylogit,data.frame(male=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE) 
title(main="Males Temperature with Fitted GLM Logistic Regression Line")
```

Any hlp?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit confusing, so this may not be what you're getting at.

Logistic regression models the probability of an event occurring. So in your case, you are modelling the probability of `males` based on data giving the proportion of `males` at three different `Temp`, e.g. 0/10, 8/12 (.66), and 8/10 (0.8). So to compare the model to the data you would have to plot the predicted response vs fraction male.

```
Temp    <- c(27.2,28.3,29.9) 
male    <- c(0,8,8) 
female  <- c(10,4,2)
Y       <- cbind(male,female)  
mylogit <- glm(Y ~ Temp, family = "binomial")
plot(Temp,predict(mylogit,type="resp"),
     type="b",col="blue",lty=2, 
     ylim=c(0,1),ylab="Fraction of Males",
     main="Males Temperature with Fitted GLM Logistic Regression Line")
points(Temp,male/(male+female),pch=16, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Your post has been very helpful. However, I believe you can superimpose a curve instead of the best line of fit. I came across a code that plotted a curve on the following link. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HSAUR/vignettes/Ch_logistic_regression_glm.pdf. I have also tried the following code, (curve(predict(Temp,male=x,type="resp"),                               add=TRUE)) but it gives me an error.

Comment: I admit the code is confusing especially with reading in a table. I was just trying out different solutions of the problem.

Comment: I managed to superimpose the curve using the following code.  ###Question 1 a
Temp<-c(27.2,28.3,29.9)
Temp
male<-c(0,8,8)
male
female<-c(10,4,2)
female
table=read.table("E:\\Book1.txt",header=T)
attach(table)
table
Y=cbind(male,female)
Y
mylogit <- glm(Y ~ Temp, family = "binomial",table)
summary(mylogit)
##question 1b
plot(Temp,predict(mylogit,type="resp"),
     type="b",col="blue",lty=2, 
     ylim=c(0,1),ylab="Fraction of Males",
     main="Males Temperature with Fitted GLM Logistic Regression Line")
curve(predict(mylogit,data.frame(Temp=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE)